# Why is data sharing in Elixir / Erlang not working for the same tuple in two maps

Tags: erlang, elixir

Given the following code

```
defmodule Test do
  def run do
    p1 = {1, 2}
    m1 = %{a: p1}
    m2 = %{a: p1}
    IO.puts :erts_debug.same(m1.a, m2.a)
    m3 = %{b: p1}
    IO.puts :erts_debug.same(m1.a, m3.b)
  end
end
```

why does `Test.run` prints this

```
iex(1)> Test.run
true  <--- expected
false <--- not true ?!
:ok
```

Why are `m1.a` and `m3.b` not the same in-memory tuple?

Answer (score 3):

**modern era update:** seems like it was fixed in ≈v1.7.

This is true for Elixir only; in Erlang the [tuple is shared](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/e3cdf8208a08fe6ceb283108729aee6315af9547/lib/compiler/test/core_alias_SUITE.erl#L57):

```
1> Tuple = {1, 2},
1> Key1 = 1,
1> Key2 = 2,
1> Map1 = #{1 => Tuple, 2 => Tuple},
1> erts_debug:same(maps:get(Key1,Map1), maps:get(Key2,Map1)).
true

2> Key3 = 3,
2> Map2 = #{3 => Tuple},
2> erts_debug:same(maps:get(Key1,Map1), maps:get(Key3,Map2)).
true
```

For Elixir, this is *probably* because of internal transpiler to erlang [duplicates maps](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/d48207555a4532c6972cd03d9f85dbb996e844a1/lib/elixir/src/elixir_map.erl#L12) or like. I’d say this could be a great bug report to Elixir core.

In your example `:erts_debug.same(m1.a, m2.a)` prints `true` only due to `:erts_debug.same(m1, m2) #⇒ true`, e.g. maps themselves share the same memory.

Comment: Could this have something to do with the fact that Elixir allows variables to be "mutable", i.e., unlike in Erlang where `A = {1, 2}` the variable `A` is bound to that tuple forever in the same scope, in Elixir it can be rebound to another value because internally it creates new variables?

Comment: @SashaFonseca Elixir does not allow variables to be mutable. It allows rebinding, and not, I don’t think it has anything to do with the above. As I said, I am positive it’s about not accurate syntax transpiling.

Comment: I understood what you meant variables as not being mutable, it's actually rebinding like you said. My usage of "mutable" was incorrect